# Need an effective simply way to enable Freestyle Line Edge detection

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

I have been working on an animation that involves some motion
of a number of mesh mode planes that have freestyle line edges on them.

There is a Freestyle Line Edge render detection issue, that I am aware of.
I am using the Blender Renderer.

I have had to use Visibility, QI Detection 0,0 in order to attain
the effect that I need. This means that I cannot use the
"always detect by default" modes.

My video absolutely must move through a relative acute angle
between the camera and the Marked Freestyle Line edges
of relevence.

I have read it suggested that there is a boolean variable solution.
I don't understand how to apply this, if it exists.
Certainly if I have lots, or too many, applicable planes
with their Freestyle Line Edges.

**Aside from just "avoiding those acute angles",
or using an "always detect" mode for them, is there a way
to have those Freestyle Line Edges detected again?**

I have posted the model file at

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?448163-Freestyle-Line-Edge-and-Animation-problem&p=3299731#post3299731

as well as

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?448209-Freestyle-Line-Edge-and-Animation-problem&p=3300012#post3300012

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I must admit to not really understanding the question - does it come down to trying to make some edges ‘always freestyle regardless of angle’? If so, there is a Mark Freestyle Edge option in Edit mode and those can be enabled via the Edge Mark option in Freestyle Line Style. If it’s not that, please can you explain a bit more.

Comment: An illustration showing the difference from your desired _result_ - i.e  which edges you are seeing that you don't want to see, and vice-versa, would help to define your problem.

Comment: If you do an f12 render and look at frames 410, 470, 480, 515, 565 and 575 you will see that there are certai line segments that are not detected.  Due to the requirement to work with with a QI(0,0) setting, I cannot specify Freestyle Line Edge settings any differently.  Does anyone know of a script, or some other setting, that I can easily use in order to have the missing Freestyle Line Edge segments appear?